# Linux, Eclipse CDT run as su

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Eclipse CDT to write an application. The application uses a third part API, which requires to run as sudo, in order to open raw sockets, etc.

In command line, I can run the program something like

```
su
./program
```

But in Eclipse CDT environment, it won't work if I press Ctrl + F11 (Run->Run Last Launched), I guess the reason is that my Linux GUI login is not su.

Is there anyway that I can run as su (with su password) in Eclipse CDT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the options you have:

1. Run Eclipse as root. (Not a very good idea, imho, but the simplest one)
2. Temporarily enable your user to use that library. (Could be messy)
3. Create a new run configuration and make a script to run your executable.(You've to enter the password everytime).
4. (@Others, feel free to add more.)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a run configuration in which you use sudo to run your application. Since `sudo` doesn't have access to a terminal if you launch it this way, it requires setting the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable in your launch configuration. The steps are as follows:

1. Creating a new Run configuration (for the sake of completeness):

   1. In eclipse, right click your executable (i.e. the result of the build of your application) to open the context menu
   2. In the context menu, go to *Run as* -> *Run configurations ...*
   3. In the *Run configurations* window that appears, right click *C/C++ Application* and click *New*.
2. Modifying the Run configuration

   1. In the Run configuration's *Main* tab, replace the *C/C++ Application* field by 

       `/usr/bin/sudo`.
   2. Go to the *Arguments* tab, and enter the path to your executable, e.g. 
       `./bin/my-executable`. Note: `sudo`'s working directory is the  eclipse project, so the path should be relative to that.
   3. If your executable requires any commandline arguments, add those, e.g. 
       `./bin/my-executable arg1 arg2`
3. Adding a way for `sudo` to ask for your password.

   1. This is the most tricky part. Since `sudo` does not have a terminal (tty) at its disposal when run from the (eclipse) gui, we need to provide it with a program that can obtain the password for it, i.e. an *askpass* program. For more info, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659904/1437100).
   2. On my system (Ubuntu 15.04), the package `ssh-askpass-gnome` provides an askpass program, as I found out by running `dpkg --get-selections | grep askpass`. Since that still didn't give me the executable name, I brute-forced the search by running 

       `sudo find -name *askpass*`. Anyway, if no such utility is installed, search for it using your favourite package manager.
   3. Once we've installed and / or located an askpass program, we can continue creating our launch configuration in eclipse; continue from step 2.3
   4. In the Run configuration window, select the *Environment* tab and click *new*.
   5. In the dialog that pops up, enter `SUDO_ASKPASS` as name and the full path to the askpass program as value, e.g. `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass`.
   6. Press *Apply* to save our changes.
4. Executing the launch configuration

   1. In the *Run configurations* window, press *Run* to launch our executable using the newly created launch configuration.
   2. A pop-up window for entering the `sudo` password will appear.
   3. After succesful password entry, our executable will run with root priviliges.