# How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?

Tags: linux, sudo, tty

I am trying to compile some sources using a makefile. In the makefile there is a bunch of commands that need to be ran as `sudo`.

When I compile the sources from a terminal all goes fine and the make is paused the first time a `sudo` command is ran waiting for password. Once I type in the password, make resumes and completes.

But I would like to be able to compile the sources in NetBeans. So, I started a project and showed netbeans where to find the sources, but when I compile the project it gives the error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

The first time it hits a `sudo` command.

I have looked up the issue on the internet and all the solutions I found point to one thing: disabling the password for this user. Since the user in question here is root. I do not want to do that.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I am compiling a toy operating system. I need to do some stuff to setup the VM, including creating a virtual hdd with boot sector.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20248009/873282

Comment: As pointed in https://serverfault.com/a/597268, `sudo -n my-command` worked for me. HIH!

Comment: Please choose an answer.

Comment: @andreyevbr i dont think so. `sudo: a password is required`

Comment: In Case if you are stuck with imports or tty or no askpass not working please check this link for details steps to execute it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978771/9470457 Thanks!!!

Comment: You don't need to disable password access for the user, just for the user *when using `sudo` to run that exact command*.

Answer (score 309):

Granting the user to use that command without prompting for password should resolve the problem. First open a shell console and type:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then edit that file to add to the very end:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /fullpath/to/command, /fullpath/to/othercommand
```

eg

```
john ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/start, /sbin/stop
```

will allow user `john` to sudo `poweroff`, `start` and `stop` without being prompted for password.

Look at the bottom of the screen for the keystrokes you need to use in visudo - this is not vi by the way - and exit without saving at the first sign of any problem. Health warning: corrupting this file will have serious consequences, edit with care!

Comment: Yes, the [sudoers man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) has opened my eyes to how sudo is actually supposed to be used.

Comment: visudo should open up in whatever EDITOR your environment is configured to use, which very well could be (and should be ^_^) vi.

Comment: Make sure the NOPASSWD mathing line is AFTER any other sudo lines that may match (like %wheel) that does not have the NOPASSWD flag.

Comment: i can't "sudo visudo" because I can't sudo in the first place!

Comment: Consider adding a file to /etc/sudoers.d and leaving the visudo file untouched.

Comment: how to do this programmatically?

Comment: But of course `NOPASSWD` is insecure in many settings. Resolving the lack of a tty as addressed in the other answers seems much wiser.

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a workaround. The only thing that helped me was an answer below (about adding the `-S` flag to `sudo`). You should target the problem and passwords are not the problem here. The error is the problem

Answer (score 212):

Try:

1. Use `NOPASSWD` line for all commands, I mean:

   ```
   jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
2. Put the line after all other lines in the `sudoers` file.

That worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: I first added the line after other user configurations, 
but it only worked when placed as absolutely last line in file on lubuntu 14.04.1.

Comment: The second part was the solution I was what I was needing. A existing configuration line (for wheel group) also matched my sudo command but without the NOPASSWD: entry.   Placing my new line after it gave it the priority, allowing no password use for the specific command I needed.

Comment: As @user77115 had mentioned, this only worked if you placed it as the last line in the sudoers file, even with Ubuntu 16.04. 

As a side note, giving sudo permissions to jenkins for all commands is a pretty large security concern. Consider wrapping your jenkins scripts and only giving access to specific commands such as:

`jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/lib/jenkins/wrapper_script`

Comment: `jenkins` is just a user name? It must be user name of user from host machine? What if user name on host machine matches user name from remote server?

Comment: this is jenkins specific, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651598/1041319 is more generic solution.

Comment: Does anybode know why I have to allow `ALL` commands instead of just the specific command (I want to allow) in the case of a Jenkins node?

Comment: Worked also on Ubuntu 18.04 for me !!

Comment: I've never had to put it at the end. There must be something else in the default file that is reverting the entry unless it's at the end.

Comment: I replaced "jenkins" with my username for Ubuntu Mate, and it fixed my issue.

Comment: 2. Put the line after all other lines in the sudoers file.  - this solved my problem

Comment: I replaced jenkins with my username and it works well. Ubuntu 18

Comment: I downvoted as this essentially removes all security or "oh wait, did I intend to run that". Honestly, it's fixing a papercut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @LarsBilke and whoever might stumble across this. Just don't do this. This removes any security and you could just run jenkins as root as well. And Jenkins is so to speak... very common and good target for attackers, who will later wreak havoc on your machine after getting root permissions. Establish which scripts Jenkins needs to run and only allow those.

Answer (score 200):

Try:

```
ssh -t remotehost "sudo <cmd>"
```

This will remove the above errors.

Comment: `-t  Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine` see also: [sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281742/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified)  Also `sudo -A` allows setting a `sudo` askpass program, but I only see GUIs.  Does anyone one know an askpass to allow `ssh remotehost sudo -A askpass` ?

Comment: Correction, The `-A` for `sudo` does not take arguments and instead requires environment `SUDO_ASKPASS` or a `sudo.conf`  So `ssh remotehost sudo -A command` would still work.  Still curious about a terminal based askpass program.

Comment: this doesn't work for me (presumably because I'm calling ssh from a script), giving me the error `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` :(

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 175):

After all alternatives, I found:

```
sudo -S <cmd>
```

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.

[Source](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html)

Above command still needs password to be entered. To remove entering password manually, in cases like jenkins, this command works:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <cmd>
```

Comment: This seems fixing my issue. But is there any side effect by using this command?

Comment: `sudo -S <command>`- `true` just happens to be a dummy command that returns an exit code of 0 (`false` is a command that returns 1).  Thank you, this is the one true answer, since all others expect "sudo" to work!

Comment: -S: Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.

Comment: This works right away, and might get sudo working until a timeout, but doesn't address whatever underlying problems might exist, and the problem can come back.

Comment: I don't know if its working but its showing `Password:` then nothing happens. I cant type in the password.

Comment: I would recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651598/3930114 above as by using this method I can see my password on the terminal

Comment: @Heemanshu, In my project I need to write some content to text file on linux sftp server, So I am using the same command as you suggested above, but I am getting an error saying permission denied.

eg. echo Testpwd | sudo -s echo hi user1 >> PathOf TheFile 

But following command is working fine.

echo Testpwd | sudo -s mkdir PathOf TheFile/file1.txt 

So I am not getting that if it is working with mkdir then why not with echo?

Comment: @Dreamer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Comment: I tried this in a GitHub action and it didn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 50):

`sudo` by default will read the password from the attached terminal. Your problem is that there is no terminal attached when it is run from the netbeans console. So you have to use an alternative way to enter the password: that is called the **askpass** program.

The **askpass** program is not a particular program, but any program that can ask for a password. For example in my system `x11-ssh-askpass` works fine.

In order to do that you have to specify what program to use, either with the environment variable `SUDO_ASKPASS` or in the `sudo.conf` file (see `man sudo` for details).

You can force `sudo` to use the askpass program by using the option `-A`. By default it will use it only if there is not an attached terminal.

Comment: Current solution requires a gui.  What askpass program works on terminal.

Comment: @here: Well... if you run ssh from a terminal, it will ask for a password directly, you don't need anything special... Or are you asking about requesting the password from a different terminal than the one that will run the ssh session?

Comment: ahh now I see that `-A` does not take arguments.  `-A` requires environment `SUDO_ASKPASS` or a `sudo.conf` file.   In that case, `ssh host "export SUDO_ASKPASS=askpass;sudo -A cat /etc/passwd"` would still work with a terminal based askpass, however @chandru is far more concise below with `ssh -t ...`

Comment: There are some cavats with using -A.   First, if -A is used and SUDO_ASKPASS has not been set you will get an error.  Second, when -A is used ssh will not use cached credentials, it will always request a password.

Comment: As a adendum you may like to look at my notes on password input programs...
http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt

Comment: Thrid, sudo does not 'wait' on the password reader. As such the program will become a zombie until the sudo command exits!

Answer (score 27):

Try this one:

```
echo '' | sudo -S my_command
```

Comment: It works for me, but can anyone explain why it helps?

Comment: @ololobus you send an empty password to first prompt to enter password

Comment: Worked! None of the higher rated answer solved it for me.

Comment: It returns following error: `[sudo] password for alper: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for alper:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
` @sNICkerssss

Comment: Didn't work on Centos 6 when running a PHP script that shell_exec another script - it's asking for apache user password.

Answer (score 27):

For Ubuntu 16.04 users

There is a file you have to read with:

```
cat /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

Placing a file with mode 0440 in /etc/sudoers.d/myuser with following content:

```
myuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Should fix the issue.

Do not forget to:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/myuser
```

Comment: Nice. Cleaner solution than the popular one.

Comment: Do not follow this blindly. I created a new file in /etc/sudoers.d as described here and ended up not being able to use sudo anymore.. had to delete the file through recovery mode.

Answer (score 18):

Login into your linux. Fire following commands. Be careful, as editing sudoer is a risky proposition.

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Once vi editor opens make the following changes:

1. Comment out `Defaults    requiretty`

   ```
   # Defaults    requiretty
   ```
2. Go to the end of the file and add

   ```
   jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

Answer (score 16):

If by any chance you came here because you can't sudo inside the Ubuntu that comes with Windows10

1. Edit the /etc/hosts file from Windows (with Notepad), it'll be located at: `%localappdata\lxss\rootfs\etc`, add `127.0.0.1 WINDOWS8`, this will get rid of the first error that it can't find the host.
2. To get rid of the `no tty present` error, always do `sudo -S <command>`

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer for people who came here for a reason unrelated to question description, but matching question title. +1

Comment: [DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
echo "myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

where your user is "myuser"

for a Docker image, that would just be:

```
RUN echo "myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 12):

*In Jenkins*:

```
echo '<your-password>' | sudo -S command
```

*Eg*:-

```
echo '******' | sudo -S service nginx restart
```

You can use [Mask Password Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) to hide your password

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the command you're `sudo`ing is part of your `PATH`.

If you have a single (or multi, but not ALL) command `sudoers` entry, you'll get the `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` when the command is not part of your path (and the full path is not specified).

You can fix it by either adding the command to your `PATH` or invoking it with an absolute path, i.e.

`sudo /usr/sbin/ipset`

Instead of

`sudo ipset`

Comment: This is actually forked for me. in `sudoers` `%sitd ALL=(lamparna) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git_push_to_lamparna.sh, /usr/bin/git` and using  `sudo -u lamparna git push --mirror ssh://lamparna@REDMINE/home/lamparna/repos/git/jine/lamparna.git` in git post-update hook return `no tty`, but using `sudo -u lamparna /usr/bin/git push --mirror ssh://lamparna@REDMINE/home/lamparna/repos/git/jine/lamparna.git` work without password.

Answer (score 6):

Command `sudo` fails as it is trying to prompt on root password and there is no pseudo-tty allocated (as it's part of the script).

You need to either log-in as root to run this command or set-up the following rules in your `/etc/sudoers`
 (or: `sudo visudo`):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges.
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then make sure that your user belongs to `admin` group (or `wheel`).

Ideally (safer) it would be to limit root privileges only to specific commands which can be specified as `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/program`

Comment: I know, that's much safer way to do. Although, I wrote the following command in `sudoers` file `apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/bin/startup.sh` but it doesn't work for me. it gives the following error `sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 120 <<< sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 120 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Comment: BTW, it works well `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` but a security risk. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think I can help someone with my case.

First, I changed the user setting in `/etc/sudoers` referring to above answer. But It still didn't work.

```
myuser   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%mygroup  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

In my case, `myuser` was in the `mygroup`.

And I didn't need groups. So, deleted that line.

(Shouldn't delete that line like me, just marking the comment.)

```
myuser   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It works!

Answer (score 2):

Running shell scripts that have contain sudo commands in them from jenkins might not run as expected. To fix this, follow along

Simple steps:

1. On ubuntu based systems, run " $ sudo visudo "
2. this will open /etc/sudoers file.
3. If your jenkins user is already in that file, then modify to look like this:

> jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

4. save the file
5. Relaunch your jenkins job
6. you shouldnt see that error message again :)

Answer (score 2):

Using pipeline:

```
echo your_pswd | sudo -S your_cmd
```

Using here-document:

```
sudo -S cmd <<eof
pwd
eof
#remember to put the above two lines without "any" indentations.
```

Open a terminal to ask password (whichever works):

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo cmd"
```

```
xterm -e "sudo cmd"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a more recent change, but I just had this problem and `sudo -S` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error may also arise when you are trying to run a terminal command (that requires root password) from some non-shell script, eg `sudo ls` (in backticks) from a Ruby program. In this case, you can use **Expect** utility (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or its alternatives.
 For example, in Ruby to execute `sudo ls` without getting `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`, you can run this:

```
require 'ruby_expect'

exp = RubyExpect::Expect.spawn('sudo ls', :debug => true)
exp.procedure do
    each do
        expect "[sudo] password for _your_username_:" do
            send _your_password_
        end
    end
end
```

[this uses one of the alternatives to **Expect** TCL extension: *ruby_expect* gem].

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, in case someone else encounter the same issue, I was stuck during a good hour with this error which should not happen since I was using the NOPASSWD parameter.

What I did NOT know was that sudo may raise the exact same error message when there is no tty and the command the user try to launch is not part of the allowed command in the /etc/sudoers file.

Here a simplified example of my file content with my issue:

```
bguser ALL = NOPASSWD: \
    command_a arg_a, \
    command_b arg_b \
    command_c arg_c
```

When bguser will try to launch "sudo command_b arg_b" without any tty (bguser being used for some daemon), then he will encounter the error "no tty present and no askpass program specified".

Why?

Because a comma is missing at the end of line in the /etc/sudoers file...

*(I even wonder if this is an expected behavior and not a bug in sudo since the correct error message for such case shoud be "Sorry, user bguser is not allowed to execute etc.")*

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I had limited my user to only a single executable 'systemctl' and had misconfigured the visudo file.

Here's what I had:

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: systemctl
```

However, you need to include the full path to the executable, even if it is on your path by default, for example:

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

This allows my jenkins user to restart services but not have full root access

Answer (score 1):

If you add this line to your `/etc/sudoers` (via `visudo`) it will fix this problem without having to disable entering your password and when an alias for `sudo -S` won't work (scripts calling `sudo`):

```
Defaults visiblepw
```

Of course read the [manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.0/sudoers.man.html) yourself to understand it, but I think for my use case of running in an LXD container via `lxc exec instance -- /bin/bash` its pretty safe since it isn't printing the password over a network.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when working on an **Ubuntu 20.04** server.

I was trying to run a `sudo` command from a remote machine to deploy an app to the server. However when I run the command I get the error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
The remote script failed with exit code 1
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue is caused by executing a `sudo` command which tries to request for a password, but `sudo` does not have access to a `tty` to prompt the user for a passphrase. As it can’t find a `tty`, `sudo` falls back to an `askpass` method but can’t find an `askpass` command configured, so the `sudo` command fails.

To fix this you need to be able to run `sudo` for that specific **user** with no password requirements. The **no password requirements** is configured in the `/etc/sudoers` file. To configure it run either of the commands below:

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

OR

```
sudo visudo
```

**Note**: This opens the `/etc/sudoers` file using your default editor.

Next, Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
# Allow members to run all commands without a password
my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

**Note**: Replace `my_user` with your actual user

If you want the user to run specific commands you can specify them

```
# Allow members to run specific commands without a password
my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/myCommand
```

OR

```
# Allow members to run specific commands without a password
my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/myCommand, /bin/myCommand, /bin/myCommand
```

Save the changes and exit the file.

For more help, read the resource in this link: [sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified](https://www.shell-tips.com/linux/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified/)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is

If you came across this issue anywhere else apart from the Jenkins instance follow this from the 2nd step. The first step is for the user who is having issue with the Jenkins instance.

Go to Jenkins instance of Google Cloud Console.
Enter the commands
sudo su

visudo -f /etc/sudoers

Add following line at the end

jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL

Checkout [here](https://blogger.askyourwebsite.com/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified/) to understand the rootcause of this issue

Answer (score 0):

No one told what could cause this error, in case of migration from one host to another, remember about checking hostname in sudoers file:

So this is my  /etc/sudoers config

```
User_Alias      POWERUSER = user_name
Cmnd_Alias SKILL = /root/bin/sudo_auth_wrapper.sh
POWERUSER hostname=(root:root) NOPASSWD: SKILL
```

if it doesn't match

```
uname -a
Linux other_hostname 3.10.17 #1 SMP Wed Oct 23 16:28:33 CDT 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

it will pop up this error:

> no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 0):

Other options, not based on NOPASSWD:

- Start Netbeans with root privilege ((sudo netbeans) or similar) which will presumably fork the build process with root and thus sudo will automatically succeed.
- Make the operations you need to do suexec -- make them owned by root, and set mode to 4755. (This will of course let any user on the machine run them.) That way, they don't need sudo at all.
- Creating virtual hard disk files with bootsectors shouldn't need sudo at all. Files are just files, and bootsectors are just data. Even the virtual machine shouldn't necessarily need root, unless you do advanced device forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I was trying to mount sshfs which required sudo; the command is something like this:

```
sshfs -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" user@my.server.tld:/var/www /mnt/sshfs/www
```

After adding the option `-o debug`

```
sshfs -o debug -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" user@my.server.tld:/var/www /mnt/sshfs/www
```

I had the same error message:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Based on other answers, I created a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/user` on my.server.tld with:

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

and now I able to mount the drive without granting too many permissions to my user.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, it is still relevant for my more or less up-to-date system. After enabling debug mode of sudo (`Debug sudo /var/log/sudo_debug all@info` in `/etc/sudo.conf`) I was pointed to /dev: "`/dev is world writable`". So you might need to **check the tty file permissions**, especially those of the directory where the tty/pts node resides in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done but please make sure to follow the steps properly.
This is for the anyone who is getting import errors.

**Step1**: Check if files and folders have got execute permission issue.
Linux user use:

```
chmod 777 filename
```

**Step2**: Check which user has the permission to execute it.

**Step3**: open terminal type this command.

```
sudo visudo
```

add this lines to the code below

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
nobody ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/ALL
```

this is to grant permission to execute the script and allow it to use all the libraries. The user generally is 'nobody' or 'www-data'.

now edit your code as

```
echo shell_exec('sudo -u the_user_of_the_file python your_file_name.py 2>&1');
```

go to terminal to check if the process is running
type this there...

```
ps aux | grep python
```

this will output all the process running in python.

**Add Ons**: 
use the below code to check the users in your system

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

Thank You!

Comment: `chmod 777` compromises your system's security; it lets even completely untrusted users like `nobody` run an executable that you're then running with `sudo`. It should **never** be recommended, and any system it was run on should be considered compromised and untrustable.

Comment: -1. Do NOT EVER use chmod 777 on an executable that is meant to be used with `sudo`. This completely destroys the purpose of `sudo` and root access itself, since as said by @CharlesDuffy EVERYONE will be able to access it without using sudo

Comment: To be clear, `777` doesn't just let everyone _access_ the executable, it also lets everyone _change_ the executable. Replace it with something with a virus or worm, for example? Sure, it's set world-writable, why not?!

Answer (score 0):

## 1 open /etc/sudoers

type `sudo vi  /etc/sudoers`. This will open your file in edit mode.

## 2 Add/Modify linux user

Look for the entry for Linux user. Modify as below if found or add a new line.

```
<USERNAME> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

## 3 Save and Exit from edit mode

Answer (score 0):

Below actions work for on ubuntu20

1. edit /etc/sudoers

```
visudo
```

or

```
vi /etc/sudoers
```

2. add below content

```
userName   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: This is really bad answer and not should be used. This grants access to `sudo` in your system without password.

Comment: Mateech: given that you're probably only seeing this issue in the first place because it's a chroot environment, i think it's fine.