# Run commands via Jenkins?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jenkins

I have a script on remote Ubuntu server. I trying to execute the script after the jenkins build is succeeded, But the error says like this:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

The configuration is given below,
[image]

Can anyone help me? 
Thank You.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your script uses `sudo` at some point. The usual way around is to add the script that requires you to use `sudo` to the sudoers.

Example: in your script you use `sudo service apache2 reload`, now create a bash script containing that line and add that script to the sudoers file.

New script name: `/home/quaser/restart-apache.sh`

Use: `visudo`

Add at bottom of the file:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/quaser/restart-apache.sh
```

Now, in your script change: `sudo service apache restart` to `sudo /home/quaser/restart-apache.sh` and you should not be asked for a password.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved that by commenting `Defaults requiretty` on `/etc/sudoers`

```
cat /etc/sudoers| grep tty
#Defaults    requiretty
```

From the man page:

```
 man sudoers | grep requiretty  -A 5
       requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in
                       to a real tty.  When this flag is set, sudo can only be
                       run from a login session and not via other means such
                       as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by
                       default.
```