# scp a directory from Python in Debian

Tags: python, linux, scp

I am trying to run a script file of all of my Debian computers in my house, the script will get the `/home/script` file from the Master machine when I call MPI to run it on all the machines. Right now I have to go onto each machine and do this command:

```
sudo scp -r max@10.0.0.216:/home/scripts /home
```

But I want it to be run within a Python script. Here's what I've come up with:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "-S", "scp", "-r", "max@10.0.0.216:/home/scripts", "/home"])
```

The error is the following:

```
    sudo: sudono tty present and no askpass program specified:
no tty present and no askpass program specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/scripts/Update-Scripts/script.py", line 3, in <module>
subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "scp", "-r", "max@10.0.0.216:/home/scripts", "/home"])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode,cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['sudo', 'scp', '-r', 'max@10.0.0.216:/home/scripts', '/home']' returned non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You are trying to run a command named `scp -r`, you want to split off the option as a separate argument `["scp", "-r", `...

Comment: If you want the `sudo` you have to add that back on, too.

Comment: Why do you want Python here, though? You are fundamentally using `scp` anyway and Python is just a worse shell than the shell for that.

Comment: @tripleee I split the -r but now I get premission denied, and when I use sudo I get a lot of errors, I will update the main post with the new line and the errors.

Comment: The error means `sudo` is not connected to a terminal so it can't ask for a password. You need to run from a place where you can supply the password interactively, or configure `sudo` to run passwordless for this command.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013242/cannot-sudo-su-anymore-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified (though not the accepted answer)

Comment: Going forward, please take care not to trample previous edits when updating your posts.

Comment: I have made public rsa keys so I can ssh to any of my machines without password, but not with scp, should it use the same keys?

Comment: `sudo` is a different program which doesn't know anything about your SSH keys; it is configured with a local configuration file. Again, please review the proposed duplicate.

Comment: When I added -S I get the error: sudo: no password was provided, how do I provide a password?