# sudoers NOPASSWD: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, tty

I have added a user like this:

```
$ adduser --system --home /no/home --no-create-home --group --disabled-password --disabled-login testuser
```

Added a user to a group:

```
$ adduser testuser testgroup
```

added lines to sudoers (visudo):

```
testuser    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%testgroup         ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

When I try to run the bash script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u testuser /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/script.php
```

But when I run this script, I get the error in the log:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Edit: `requiretty` is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: Aren't `sudo` permissions about the user/group you are changing *from* not the user you are changing *to*? So aren't those lines letting the `testuser` user and the `testgroup` group run any command (as anyone) without a password? Don't you need to give permission to the user running the script to run commands *as* the `testuser` for what you want? Assuming that's what you meant to allow?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have tried it too, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You tried *what* too? Running `sudo` as the testuser? What specifically did you run/try? What user is running the original script?

Comment: @EtanReisner You were right. I had to add NOPASSWD for the client's group. Now it works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified -- netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-netbeans)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo` permissions are about the user/group you are changing *from* not the user you are changing *to*.

So are those permission lines are letting the `testuser` user and the `testgroup` group run any command (as anyone) without a password.

You need to give permission *to* the user running the script to run commands *as* the `testuser` user for what you want.

Assuming that's what you meant to allow that is.

Answer (score 4):

That error occurs when your sudoers file specifies `requiretty`. From the `sudoers` manpage:

> ```
>    requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is 
>                    logged in to a real tty.  When this flag is set, 
>                    sudo can only be run from a login session and not 
>                    via other means such as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  
>                    This flag is off by default.
> ```

To fix your error, remove `requiretty` from your sudoers file.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. requiretty is not in the sudoers file. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by login to the server and append the following lines to the ssh-server configuration:

```sh
> vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match User <your user name>
    PermitTTY yes
```

So I don't need the `-t` options permanently.