# Paramiko error when trying to edit file: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: python, linux, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to SSH and edit a config file. The file itself needs sudo permissions to edit. This hasn't been a problem so far, as I've just done `echo <sudopw> | sudo <command>` for other sudo commands in my script.

When I try to edit this file using sed, though, nothing happens. `stderr` produces: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Here is my code:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command
('echo <sudopassword> | sudo sed -i -e \"\\$aAllowUsers\" /etc/ssh/sshd_config)')
```

I have tried solutions using `invoke_shell` but nothing seems to be working. Any solution to edit this file would be helpful.

**EDIT: This has been solved! Don't use `get_pty`. Use the -S option of sudo right after "sudo".**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164572/7601752 I found this to be the best solution, look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the error message

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

then you can easily find the solution: add the `-t` option to your [ssh](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1) command:

> **`-t`**
>   
>     Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple **`-t`** options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

This has been discussed before:

- [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)
- [sudoers NOPASSWD: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697348/sudoers-nopasswd-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified)

Regarding Paramiko, there have been related questions, with a couple of different approaches:

- use the [`get_pty`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.get_pty) method of the ssh `Channel` to obtain a pseudo-terminal (which is analogous to telling `ssh` to do this)
- use the `-S` option of `sudo`, and send the password on your standard output.

For discussion, see the suggested answers here:

- [Paramiko and Pseudo-tty Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909481/paramiko-and-pseudo-tty-allocation)
- [Nested SSH session with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko)