# Running vcgencmd from php exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec

When I run `vcgencmd measure_temp` in the terminal, it gives the temperature reading of the cpu.

But when i use the same command in php `exec('vcgencmd measure_temp 2>&1')` it gives following error in the browser:

> VCHI initialization failed

How can `vcgencmd`command be executed from php?

Comment: I am sure PHP already uses rapid rises and falls in cpu temperature to communicate in primitive SOS language with the Gerbils in your pc. The Gerbils must therefore have an exclusive lock on the cpu temperature.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=34076 <-- this suggests updating the firmware/restarting will fix it.

Comment: Could be permissions issue. Try `exec ('sudo vcgencmd measure_temp 2>&1')`.

Comment: @Samuel  Using sudo gives following error in the browser                               'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified'

Comment: Check that link, to configure sudoers file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107529/524743

Answer (score 7):

You have to add user 'www-data' to group named 'video'. You can do add by executing this command as sudo:

```
sudo usermod -aG video www-data
```

It will help after reboot.
If it will not help, try to check username of script executor by writing this code:

```
<?php
echo(exec("whoami"));
?>
```

And add printed user to group 'video'.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is also useful to run `vcgencmd` as non-root user from command line.