# Capistrano "No tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, capistrano

I'm running `cap production deploy` and I keep getting the following error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` after `/usr/bin/env sudo mkdir -pv /home/[user]/apps/[app name] as [user@myIP]`

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/safe_deploy_to'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution would be to [allow the sudo command on your server without entering a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error), but that could be a security risk.

Alternatively, you can fix your Capistrano configuration because something is likely wrong. It would help if you showed us the contents of your `deploy.rb` file but first thing I would do is ensure that you have `default_run_options[:pty]` set to `true` in `deploy.rb`. Or add the line if you're missing it.

**Capistrano 2**

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

**Capistrano 3**

```
set :pty, true
```

Comment: Password shows like simple text and on entering nothing happens

Comment: Bump - this is also happening to me. I can enter my password as plaintext but nothing happens when I hit enter.

Comment: Same issue for me. I have searched the entire internet for answers, nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

On server open visudo file for editing:

```rb
sudo visudo
```

and list all commands that your deployment user is allowed to run without entering password, eg.:

```
deploy_user        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: \
  /bin/systemctl status puma_production, \
  /bin/systemctl start puma_production, \
  /bin/systemctl stop puma_production, \
  /bin/systemctl restart puma_production
```

save the file and try to run capistrano command again. You could allow all commands by `NOPASSWD:ALL` but it's considered not safe ofc as for unprivileged user.

Note: ensure your executable path is full – eg. not `systemctl` but `/bin/systemctl`, which you can get by `which systemctl` command