# Run scrapy from Flask application

Tags: python, nginx, flask, scrapy

I have a crawler which I want to run everytime a person goes to the link. Since all the other modules are in Flask, I was told to build this in Flask also. I have installed scrapy and selenium both in the virtual environment and globally on the machine with root.

When I run the crawler through the terminal, everything works fine. When I start the Flask application and visit `xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/whats` in the browser, this also works fine and runs my crawler and gets me the file. But as soon as I go live so that anytime a person goes to the link, it gives me internal error in browser.

In order to run crawler, we have to type "scrapy crawl whateverthespidernameis" in the terminal. I did this using Python's `os` module.

Here is my flask code:

```
import sys
from flask import request, jsonify, render_template, url_for, redirect,   session, abort,render_template_string,send_file,send_from_directory
from flask import *
#from application1 import *
from main import *
from test123 import *
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

filename = ''
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/whats')
def whats():
    os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("/var/www/myapp/whats")
    //cmd = "scrapy crawl whats"
    cmd = "sudo scrapy crawl whats"
    os.system(cmd)
    return send_file("/var/www/myapp/staticcsv/whats.csv", as_attachment =True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080,debug=True)
```

This is the error recorded in the log file when I run through live link:

```
sh: 1: scrapy: not found**
```

This is the error recorded in the log file when I use sudo in the command (variable `cmd`):

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**
```

I am using uwsgi and nginx.

How can I run this crawler so that when anyone goes to "xx.xx.xx.xx/whats" the crawler runs and returns the csv file?

Comment: Does your code really have the line `cmd = "sudo crapy crawl whats"` (note the invocation of a program named `crapy`)?

Comment: you are using the python os command ' cmd = "sudo crapy crawl whats" '. I think it should be ' cmd = "sudo scrapy crawl whats" '. And the next point is that check your scrapy PATH, correct it. It will run without any error. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in post, I have edited that

Comment: I answered similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384286/how-to-integrate-flask-scrapy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `sudo` the shell this starts will ask for a password on the tty - it specifically doesn't read standard input for this information. Since `flask` and other web applications typically run detached from a terminal, `sudo` has no way to ask for a password, so it looks for a program that can provide the password. You can find more information on this topic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error).

The reason you aren't finding `scrapy` is most likely because of differences in your `$PATH` between the interactive shells you used in testing and the process that's running `flask`. The easiest way to get around this is to give the full path to the `scrapy` program in your command.

Comment: Note that one potential cause of this sort of situation is that your virtualenv is active during development but not activated for a deployed version.

Comment: What do you mean by "shell this starts"?

Comment: I will try to give the full path and see if that works

Comment: @holdenweb Thank you it worked like a charm, writing the crawler and code took me hardly 3 to 4 hours. I was stuck in making it live since 2 days. I can't believe it didn't strike me to add full path. Besides that was a nice point that "flask and other web applications typically run detached from a terminal"

Comment: By "shell this starts" I meant the sub-shell in which the `sudo` command is run - a sub-shell  must be used because it needs to have a different process environment. Glad you have solved your problem.