# Custom Linux Hosting Control Panel in PHP - running commands as root

Tags: php, linux, nginx, root

I want to work on a custom linux hosting control panel based on my experience in managing LEMP/LAMP stack. This is just a pet project. I believe I have ran into some hurdle.

The CP is being written in PHP and server by NginX as default server on port 8000.
I am not using any framework, just vanilla PHP.

In putty, logged in as root, I can get the system uuid like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmidecode -s system-uuid
997C4DE8-213B-4ACC-8E23-01E79D6CC12F
```

When I try this in PHP with the following script:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('dmidecode -s system-uuid 2>&1'));
```

I get the following:

> sh: dmidecode: command not found

How can I execute that above command get the output in PHP?

Nginx/PHP-FPM is running as user `nginx`. Do i need to add nginx user to root group?

I want to be able to execute very specific commands like: `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart` from my control panel (to restart php-fpm gateway).

How can I achieve this? What are my options? How does control panel like cPanel, DirectAdmin, etc... do it?

### Update

I have tried the following method also. Installed `sudo` and used the `sudo visudo` command and added the following lines at the end:

```
nginx    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/path/to/php_shell.sh
Defaults:nginx        !requiretty
```

and the content of `php_shell.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

Now, I tried to execute it like this:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('sudo sh /path/to/php_shell.sh 2>&1'));
```

I get: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: That specific error most likely stems from the `PATH` not including `/usr/sbin` per default. And generally: admin panels usually have a privileged daemon run, or use some setuid script to invoke system commands.

Comment: How you to give extra privileges one quick and *very dirty* approach is to use sudo and give the sudo rights to your apache user. This is very bad for security. But the job will be done

Comment: @Ôrel when I try to use sudo in my command, I get this error: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` (will this go away when i nginx sudo rights)? Is it bad for security because any hosted site that is exploiled be able to execute system commands?

Comment: The answer depends very much of the setup your distribution made which you did not tell us. It is very hard to give a general answer to such a question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: @Ôrel I have updated my post with the attempt with using sudo, not having much luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it thanks to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284644/2332336

This is what I had to do:

Installed `sudo` and used the `sudo visudo` command and added the following lines at the end:

```
nginx    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/path/to/php_shell.sh,/bin/bash
Defaults:nginx        !requiretty
```

and the content of php_shell.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

Now, I tried to execute it like this:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('sudo /bin/bash /path/to/php_shell.sh 2>&1'));
```

Output I get:

```
string(36) "997C4DE8-213B-4ACC-8E23-01E79D6CC12F"
```

---

Now that this is working, I just need to know if this will be secure since I am ONLY ever executing a set specific commands like `dmidecode -s system-uuid` and take no user input. Or, have I have opened some sort of security hole by adding `nginx` on `visudo` like that?

Comment: If you only do `dmidecode -s system-uuid` you can have a root cron doing this command regularly and saving the output into a file than nginx can read. So nginx will only read this file.