# How to ask password for sudo using pyqt?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
cmd = subprocess.run(["sudo", "ovs-vsctl", "list-br"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

This is the error message that gets shown when I try to run it.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

This is a PyQt5 application I am trying out. So I want to know how can I ask for the administrator password in this GUI app?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys, design, subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

    def browse_folder(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()

        cmd = subprocess.run(["sudo", "ovs-vsctl", "list-br"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        bridges = cmd.stdout.split('\n')

        if bridges:
            for bridge in bridges:
                self.listWidget.addItem(bridge)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your python program is a GUI, but sudo will ask for a password on a tty or pseudo-tty. You might find some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21659637/507028).

Comment: How can I use a GUI and run this program as a normal user and only ask the user for administrative access when required?