# Unable to edit hosts or pf.conf file using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I am trying to edit `hosts` file. But it gives error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.

I have tried but its not working. Please help if anyone know.
Thank You.

```
NSMutableString* pfConf = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile: @"/private/etc/pf.conf" encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
if ([pfConf rangeOfString: @"/private/etc/pf.anchors/org.eyebeam"].location == NSNotFound) {
  [pfConf appendString: @"\n"
   "anchor \"org.eyebeam\"\n"
   "load anchor \"org.eyebeam\" from \"/private/etc/pf.anchors/org.eyebeam\"\n"];
}
[pfConf writeToFile: @"/private/etc/pf.conf" atomically: true encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

Comment: Thanks @Mihriban Minaz. Yes, I get it. But I am new to this. So do you know how to edit pf.conf without using sudo in our programming. I mean I would like to use some built in function. Please reply if you know.