# Run script in Django

Tags: python, django, shell, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to run a script in Django. This script needs to be run with sudo and I have setup the sudoers file so that the command can be executed without entering the sudo password. When I am using the default test server, ie >python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, the script executes with no problem. However, after deploying Django with Nginx and uWSGI, the command fails and returns the response

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Is there some sort of configuration that I have missed?

I am using subprocess to execute the script and the code inside the Django view is like this:

```
subprocess.check_output( "sudo /path/to/file/fileName.sh", shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure even the user that uwsgi is running as has permission to run the script without providing a password? Did you check that your sudoers file does not contain the `requiretty` option?

Comment: Its better, if you can write a python code which will do what the script does and put that python code on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the user you are using to the sudoers list:

> Granting the user to use that command without prompting for password should resolve the problem. First open a shell console and type:
>
> `sudo visudo`
>
> Then edit that file to add to the very end:
>
> `username ALL = NOPASSWD: /fullpath/to/command, /fullpath/to/othercommand`
>
> eg
>
> `john ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/start, /sbin/stop`
>
> will allow user 'john' to sudo poweroff, start and stop without being prompted for password.
>
> Look at the bottom of the screen for the keystrokes you need to use in visudo - this is not vi by the way - and exit without saving at the first sign of any problem. Health warning: corrupting this file will have serious consequences, edit with care!

source: [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is the command doesn't work in the deployed Django

Comment: Which user is running the script? it's that user that have to be added to the sudoers list, (btw it's really not secure to run a web app using a sudoer user).

Comment: The user running the script is the same as the sudoers file. John like the example above.

Comment: But in normal cases Nginx uses the "www-data" user, if your script is automated so it run's on some web related events it will be executed by www-data.