# How do I run a unix command with sudo user while pushing my app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, sudo, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to push a nodejs app in cloud foundry and js in turn calls the shell script, which includes some installation commands. During the shell script execution i am getting the following error:

```
2016-07-13T12:13:28.80+0000 [App/0]      OUT stderrsudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
2016-07-13T12:13:28.80+0000 [App/0]      OUT E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
2016-07-13T12:13:28.80+0000 [App/0]      OUT E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "js has inturn the shell script which some installation command"?

Comment: Js in turn calls the shell script and it has some installation commands. During the shell script execution i am getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

From the output you provided I suppose that your remote user can not run `apt-get` as root without a password. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error) for an instructions how to enable passwordless command execution.