# sudo: command not found while using plink

Tags: bash, unix

Hi i have created a batch file **(run.bat)** that after execution connects me to UNIX server with help of **plink**. But issue starts from this point i have to execute a script after connection to my server the script contains a command **sudo -l**. After the execution i get the error as mentioned in subject can anyone help me on this issue ??

**Batch File-:**

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY" plink -ssh -pw Tos@12Ts w44dvftyw@caa1607UX009.wvd.abcd.net /opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh
```

**Script file(run.sh) -:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -l
```

It says

> sudo: command not found

But when i run my script normally on UNIX server it runs with no issues. What am i missing here to make it work this way please help.

Comment: You might want to mask usernames and passwords when posting on a public forum

Comment: @mjsqu this is not orignal password or userid

Comment: Replacing your command with `"bash -x /opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh"` might be useful. If it literally just says that `sudo -l` is what's being run, and not something like `sudo -l$'\r'`, that tells us strongly that we need to adjust the PATH.

Comment: Check if the user w44dvftyw is added to sudoers (sudo) group.

Comment: (on which point: Also try sending as a remote command `declare -p PATH`, and compare that to the value you have with an interactive shell).

Comment: @Yore, that would be a different error message, no? Or are you supposing a system where `sudo` is only `g+x` and not `o+x`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy let me try.

Comment: I don't think so. When you can't see the command the message is like this.

Comment: @Yore, agreed, but on most systems `sudo` is world-executable, but *configured* not to perform escalations for users not in the pertinent group. That said, it is certainly *possible* to configure it as you're supposing.

Comment: @Yore i am able to sudo normally on server but not from batch file.

Comment: @TusharSharma Usually these problems are caused by lack of permission in some way.

Comment: @Yore i have given full permissions to file chmod 777 to my file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy still facing same issue after running "bash -x /opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh"

Comment: @TusharSharma, that's not intended to *solve* the issue, it's intended to give you debugging output.

Comment: BTW, `chmod 777` is a **really** bad idea, and shouldn't be done even for temporary debugging -- it gives anonymous users, including accounts like `nobody` used to run code that hasn't successfully authenticated yet, write access to content you're running as code. (Granted, those accounts should never get to filesystem access, but sandboxing as the `nobody` account is done precisely because control over them is sometimes questionable).

Comment: @charles Duffy This it what it gives + sudo -l
/opt/sie/w44gasdfdf/a.sh: line 3: sudo: command not found

Comment: @TusharSharma, thank you -- that's helpful (it rules out hidden characters in the remote file). And `declare -p PATH`, compared against the interactive version?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy did't get you where to add -p ?

Comment: Run a new command, `declare -p PATH` (or `printf 'PATH=%q\n' "$PATH"`), both as an argument passed as a script to be run, and interactively direct on the remote system (in the scenario where `sudo` works).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy now i got this (bash -x /opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh
+ declare -p PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"
+ sudo -l
/opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh: line 4: sudo: command not found)

Comment: okay, so the `PATH` includes only `/usr/bin` and `/bin`. Now, in an interactive shell, do you get the same thing? And more importantly, what does `type sudo` return (in an interactive shell where `sudo` works properly)? If it shows a location other than `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, well, there's your problem.

Comment: @TusharSharma Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error see if that helps you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy at my unix server where sudo works similar command prints this output- : declare -x PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin"

Comment: "At my UNIX server" -- the *same* server or a *different* server? If it's a different server, the one with the failure may just not have `sudo` installed at all.

Comment: (and the output from `type sudo` is still important -- it'll tell us where on the system `sudo` is being found, out of all those possible locations in the PATH).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy different server .

Comment: Then how do you know the one saying it can't find `sudo` even *has* `sudo` at all? I mean, that's the obvious answer...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i am not getting you i created a bat script which connects me to unix box using plink and i can manually login to that server using putty as well.And when i run sudo -l there it ask for password .

Comment: If you can manually log in, **then do that, and then run `declare -p PATH` and `type sudo` inside that interactive session**.

Comment: If you use a completely different machine to run tests about whether and where `sudo` is installed, as opposed to the machine you're using `plink` to connect to, then *of course* the results of those tests are invalid.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i already provided you output for declare -p PATH other one gives this -: sudo is hashed (/usr/local/bin/sudo)

Comment: There's your problem! It's in `/usr/local/bin`, but only `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in your PATH.

Comment: Just put the line `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` at the front of your script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks sir let me try

Comment: (correcting "at the front" -- it should still be *after* the shebang, but *before* the invocation of `sudo`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy after running it says this now sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: @TusharSharma Repeating my previous comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scripts such as `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` responsible for setting up the current user's `PATH` are run only on login shells.

Running `sh -c 'somescript'` (as performed by `ssh host 'somescript'`) is neither a login shell, nor an interactive shell; thus, it does not gain the benefit of such scripts.

This means that additions to the `PATH` (in your case, `/usr/local/bin`) may not be present with commands run in this way.

Among your options:

- Pass the PATH you want as part of the command to remotely run. This might look like:

  ```
  plink -ssh user@host "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /opt/sieb/w44dvftyw/run.sh"
  ```
- Embed a working value in the script you're running:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin 
  # ...put the rest of your script here.
  ```