# Executing command on Plink command line fails with "not found"

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

Goal: connect to AntMiner via SSH, and send `poweroff` command.

command: `plink.exe -v -t -ssh antminer -l root -pw xxx poweroff`

```
Connecting to 10.0.1.11 port 22  
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70  
Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2012.55  
Using SSH protocol version 2  
Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"  
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1  
Host key fingerprint is:  
ssh-rsa 1039 xxx  
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption  
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm  
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm  
Using username "root".  
Sent password  
Access granted  
Opening session as main channel  
Opened main channel  
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)  
Started a shell/command  
sh: poweroff: not found  
Server sent command exit status 127  
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

So the connection is working fine, it's the sending of the command that goes wrong.
Here's what SHOULD happen: (sent the command manually this time)

command: `plink.exe -v -t -ssh antminer -l root -pw xxx`

```
Connecting to 10.0.1.11 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2012.55
Using SSH protocol version 2
Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1039 xxx
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "root".
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
root@antMiner:~# poweroff

Broadcast message from root@antMiner (pts/0) (Thu Jan 25 19:23:19 2018):

The system is going down for system halt NOW!
root@antMiner:~# Server unexpectedly closed network connection
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Anybody have any idea WHY the sending of the command "poweroff" over plink fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in these questions:

- [Script via Plink in .bat behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38313389/850848)
- [sudo: command not found while using plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44702874/850848)

---

So one easy solution is that you can try `which poweroff` in a normal session, to see where `poweroff` resides (can be `/sbin/poweroff`). And then use a full path in your `plink` command-line.

Though the right solution is to fix your startup scripts. See the links above.

---

As your command-line does not work even with the `-t` switch, your SSH server must execute a command in "exec" channel (used when a command is provided on command-line or using `-m` switch) differently than in a "shell" channel. This is rather unusual.

You can force `plink` to use "shell" channel (like in an interactive session) by using an input redirection:

```
echo poweroff| plink ...
```

Comment: after using which poweroff, It was indeed in /sbin/poweroff.