# Run linux command without password that need root permission

Tags: node.js

I'm using node to execute bash command on Linux. I need to stop and start apache server. Normally from bash you need to type:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

and you need to insert the password. To change that I modify the 'visudo' after modification is not asking for a password but when I run this from node I get error

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo systemctl status apache2.service
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Where is the problem? The node code looks like that

```
app.get('/StatusTest', function(req, res){
    exec("sudo systemctl status apache2.service", function(err, stdout){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(stdout);
        res.render('statustest');
   });
})
```

Comment: I also used 'sudo service apache2 stop' and 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop' but result is thesame

Comment: Does the Node server run as the same user that you allowed passwordless access to with `visudo`?

Comment: Yes, of course I'm running node from the same user who is in visudo

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` from a new shell to see if it _really_ doesn't ask for a password? What exactly did you add with `visudo`?

Comment: cyprian ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2

Comment: But you're executing `systemctl`, not `/etc/init.d/apache2`...

Comment: look comment above

Comment: A number of solutions can be found in a related problem here (using the arguments -t or -A or using echo with pipe etc) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error

Comment: Oooo @robertklep you have right when I open new shell it's asking for a password, why is like that?

Comment: @cyprian I guess because `sudo` doesn't think you're allowed to call it without a password (however, typically, once you entered your password you have something like 10 or 15 minutes in which subsequent calls to `sudo` will work passwordless). What you added with `visudo` _looks_ okay to me, so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command for automatic password input:

```
exec(`echo 'your_sudo_password' | sudo -S systemctl status apache2.service`, ...);
```