# Q: Why randomly getting 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, sudoers

We are running Jenkins in a docker container and using the Docker-outside-of-Docker approach. As is well documented, we added:

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to /etc/sudoers.

- http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/
- [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

The problem we face is that our pipeline job randomly fails when executing the first make command:

```
sudo -E make login
```

with the error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Why are we experiencing this error only sometimes?

Comment: can you try starting the container with the `-t` option? Another thing to try is starting it with `--user root` and avoid using `sudo`

Comment: Adding 'user: root' to my docker-compose file and removing sudo -E from the make commands solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the issue like as mentioned below
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHOxI.jpg)

Login to the instance in GitBash and open the following file.

`sudo visudo`

And in this file Add the following command in the end of the file

`jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Save the file and Run the Jenkins onnce again.
Hope your issue will be solve.
Thanks!
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhVnt.png)

Comment: thank you. this is what we did actually.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to share code snippets, use code blocks instead! That goes both for questions and answers. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557