# Using "sudo cp" in an R program that runs in Linux ubuntu 17.04

Tags: r, linux

I am running this code in a R program, but In order to be able to use linux commands from the shell, I need to invoke sudo first.  For instance, if I want to copy a file "cp file.tsv file_copy.txt" I have to write "sudo cp file.tsv file_copy.txt.Is it possible to use sudo in the code? How should I do that?

```
if (paste(dirname(inFileName), “/”, sep="") != OUTpath ) {
OS<- Sys.info()[“sysname”] 
if (OS==“Windows”) {
copyCommand<- “copy”
} else {
copyCommand<- “cp”
}

   paramsCopyFn<- sub(".tsv", "_copy.txt", paramsCopyFn, fixed=T)
   cmd1<- paste(copyCommand, shQuote(inFileName), shQuote(paramsCopyFn) , sep=" ")  
   execSystemCmd(cmd1)  
  }

execSystemCmd<- function(cmd, OS=NULL) {
  if (is.null(OS)) OS<-  Sys.info()["sysname"] 
  if (OS=="Windows") {
    shell(cmd, translate=TRUE)
  } else {
    system(cmd)
  }
```

Comment: Can you run the code from a terminal with sudo directly ?

Comment: I have tried copyCommand<- paste("sudo", "",  "cp"), but I get the following error. 
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
s

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107529/2190251

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been reading about sudo and its security issues and I realized that I was using the wrong approach. One does not need to prefix the "cp" command with sudo. On the other hand, I can copy/rename a file in R using the functions copy() and rename()

Answer (score 1):

Open R as sudo using `gksu` or `sudo /path/to/R/binary`. It should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to try that.  I am working with the RStudio IDE.  I will try the command with the RStudio console.