# What are the alternative approaches to install Azure CLI on Ubuntu without root access?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am struggling to install Azure CLI on a Ubuntu machine without root access.

The instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest) assume that we have root access (or reasonable sudo access).

I am trying to run this on a Ubuntu machine (provided by IBM DevOps toolchain - root access will never be granted) where executing the sudo command results in:

```
AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | \
     sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

This results in **sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**

[Why do I need a tty to run sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password/122624#122624) has some answers however I am not able to use them as I don't have control over the login to the shell via ssh.

I am using the IBM Cloud's DevOps toolchain to deploy applications to both IBM Cloud and Azure.

The DevOps toolchain provides me a shell for me to execute commands.

Are there other alternatives

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the required prerequisites installed, you can either use the [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest) or plain 'ole pip to install the Azure CLI (pip install azure-cli). Personally, I often use the [docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/run-azure-cli-docker?view=azure-cli-latest) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the script [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest#install-or-update),

```
curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
```

I do not see why sudo would be required to install `az`. The install script downloads a python script ([this one](https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/install.py)) and runs it. This script basically

1. Downloads virtualenv
2. creates a virtual env at `~/lib/azure-cli`
3. calls `pip install azure-cli` on that virtual env
4. writes a a shell script to `~/bin/az` named `az` that runs `python -m azure.cli` and give it some permissions
5. adds completion (tab) to `az`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, this is possible. Root permission is required. You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error) to solve your issue, but I think you should have root permission to do this.

If possible, I suggest you could use [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) to run cli command on Azure.