# Executing sudo command from Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, sudo

I am trying to execute a python script from a Spark scala job in cluster mode like shown below.

```
import scala.sys.process._

Process("sudo -n python helloWorld.py").!!
```

I get "sudo: a password is required" message.

I tried setting NOPASSWD as explained in [link](http://I%20get%20%22sudo:%20a%20password%20is%20required%22%20message.%20%20%20I%20tried%20setting%20NOPASSWD%20as%20explained%20in%20the%20below%20link,%20however%20it%20didnot%20work.%20I%20still%20get%20the%20same%20error.%20%20%20[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error][1]) for the user by adding a line at the end of the file using 'sudo visudo' like below:

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However it did not work. I still get the same error. What could be wrong?

Comment: are you sure that that job is running with the correct user? try running the command `whoami` to get the actual user

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with using `dmidecode` in my python program which use 'sudo' for running some command. I ran `dmidecode` on docker and didn't have any error.

I think it's because of docker running in root mode and every package and requirement for my python program set in root mode. But in 'ubuntu' I did all setting in "sudo user" which reference to root for execute 'sudo' command and my root user didn't any setting.

As mentioned, my submit was:

```
sudo ~/spark/bin/spark-submit --name tets --master spark://10.28.10.9:5050 --executor-cores 4 
                              --executor-memory 6G --files use.npy --py-files a.zip main.py
```

but in docker was:

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --name tets --master spark://10.28.10.9:5050 --executor-cores 4 
                         --executor-memory 6G --files use.npy --py-files a.zip main.py
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: are you sure that your output of 'sudo whoami' command is 'root' and set '%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' on visudo? the last set NOPASSWD for all sudo user.

Answer (score 0):

Is that process is start from spark driver? You should run spark application as sudo user.

Comment: whoami shows user as yarn.  I have  NOPASSWD set for this user like below:                                                                      yarn ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: @vijay Did you run `whoami` in executor or driver? If you run that in method like foreachPartition, it's executor. Executor is started by yarn.

Comment: I ran whoami on the driver.