# Error while using usseradd from perl code : cannot lock /etc/passwd

Tags: perl, unix

I am writing a perl program for user administration, and I keep getting this error:
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
I run the program using su -c command, the code below is the relevant snippet - full code at https://github.com/Kajkacz/ASU_Indexing/blob/master/Users.pl .

```
sub createUserPage{

    $Mw->destroy;
    $Mw = MainWindow->new;
    $Mw->geometry("500x300");
    $Mw->title("Create User");
    my $uid = &getFreeUID;
    my $uspasswd = &randomizePassword;
    my $usname = 'UsernameHere';

    my $username = $Mw->Entry(-textvariable=> \$usname )->grid($Mw->Label(-text => 'Username'));
    my $UID = $Mw->Entry(-textvariable=> \$uid )->grid($Mw->Label(-text => 'UID'));
    my $password = $Mw ->Entry(-textvariable=> \$uspasswd)->grid($Mw->Label(-text => 'Password'));

    $Mw->Button(-text=>"Create User", -command =>sub{&createUser($uid,$usname,$uspasswd)},-width => $buttonWidth)->grid();
    $Mw->Button(-text=>"Check If UID is free", -command =>sub{&checkUID($uid)},-width => $buttonWidth)->grid();
    $Mw->Button(-text=>"Get Random Password", -command =>sub{$uspasswd = &randomizePassword},-width => $buttonWidth)->grid();

    $Mw->Button(-text=>"Back to Main Menu", -command =>sub{&getStartWindow},-width => $buttonWidth)->grid();}

sub createUser{
     my $UID = shift;
     my $username =     shift;
     my $password = shift;
     my $adduser = '/usr/sbin/useradd';
     my $cmd = qq($adduser \"$username\");
     # my $cmd = qq($adduser \"$username\" -p \"$password\" -u $UID);
     print "$cmd \n";
     system $cmd; }
```

I'd welcome any insight possible.Also, my first ever Perl program, so feel free to correct my code

Comment: That's just two function definitions; running this code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Don't call subroutines with `&`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: @melpomene Hey, sorry, first time posting on SO, hope that's better. There's a link to github above, whole code is a little long, so I don't want to post it here in full.Should I do that? I use strict and warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a fix by using this solution : [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)
and making useradd to the list of commmands run without password prompt.Not sure if hacky or good solution