# nvim writing as sudo gives error: no tty present

Tags: vim, sudo, neovim

When I'm editing a system file with Neovim, I try to save it as root using

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

However, instead of being asked for password, I get

```
:w !sudo tee %                                                                                                              
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

shell returned 1
```

How can I solve this?

I see suggestion here [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error) to tell sudo not to ask for password. I'd rather not do that (or somehow do it safely without letting nvim just modify all system files).

Comment: Known problem for neovim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8217 (tagged: wontfix)

Comment: This plugin seems to be a workarround: https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim