# Pm2 deploy Permission Denied for everythings

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to deploy an app on my server with pm2.
When i try to deploy it i have a some permissions issues.

For exemple i can not install something with `npm` globaly, i can not run an `apt-get install`, and it can't even run the `"path"` which should create the 'workdir' of the project...

Here is my config with blank infos :

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "script": "scripts/start.js"
    }
  ],
  "deploy": {
    "production": {
      "user": "namedUser",
      "host": ["**.**.**.**"],
      "ref": "origin/master",
      "repo": "git@github.com:***",
      "path": "/var/www/production",
      "pre-setup": "sudo apt-get install git nodejs npm; npm i -g yarn; yarn",
      "post-setup": "ls -la",
      "post-deploy": "yarn start"
    }
  }
}
```

But pm2 can't execute any of thes.

When i try to install something in the `"pre-setup"` i get this error from npm (event with a sudo) :

```
checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "yarn"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

And when i remove everythings i want to install except the `"path"` i get this :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add you user to the sudo group to make it able to use "sudo".

```
# usermod -aG sudo username
```

You need to make the user the owner or in the owner group of "/var/www".

```
# chown username /var/www/
```

and you need to [fix npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) to be able to install packages globally.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but it seems now i have a new error.
`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
And this dosen't help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error

**Edit :** I will open a new thread.

Comment: Actually the issue is now about allowing the user to use sudo without adding a password. So yeah, It would need a new thread. as this one is "technically" answered, you can close this one now I guess.

Comment: Here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430173/can-not-fix-the-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error