# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified error message is displayed while running shell script from Mac automator

Tags: bash, macos, shell, automator

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` error message is displayed while running shell script from Mac automator. Please let me know how to fix this ?

Shell Script is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=2;i<256;i++))
do
    sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.$i up
done
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: I have executed this code from Mac Automator

Comment: It seems duplicate in view of the already available [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error). Check the mentioned post. You'll find required answer.