# pip install awscli : pip: command not found?

Tags: python, yaml, devops, aws-cli

I'm started gitlab DevOps implementation. Everything is going fine. Just i am stuck with following error:

```
pip: command not found
```

I am started my gitlab pipeline. All stages succeed. Just except below script line where my operation is stucked:

```
  script:
    - pip install awscli
```

**Error**:

```
$ pip install awscli
bash: line 77: pip: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you check that the folder containing pip is in your PATH?

Comment: check which python version you are using. If you are using python3 then you have to install pip3 if 2.7 then pip

Comment: Actually i'm running this script under gitlab-ci.yml. means execution running on runner

Answer (score 2):

Try `pip3 install awscli` instead of `pip install awscli`.

> If it doesn't help, use `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: sudo apt install python3-pip .. sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: Open up the sudoers file for editing in your favorite editor.

vi /etc/sudoers
And add your gitlab runner user to the bottom. If you installed your gitlab runner from the official apt repositories then your gitlab-runner process will run under the gitlab-runner user.

Add the following to the bottom of the file:

gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 1):

Install pip for your linux distro, more info in the link below:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers

Answer (score 1):

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Python 3.x

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 --version
```

python 2.x

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
pip --version
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error : sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281742/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error try this for above error.