# Problem during deployment from Jenkins to mule server

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

When i try to deploy my jar file from jenkins located in AWS Instance to mule standalone server , i am facing the below issue. Please help me in resolving it.

```
+ sudo su- cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Addition/addition/target/addition-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar /home/ec2-user/mate/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.3.0/apps

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Share us the jenkins job you have used! Also I can suggest you another ways a little better to deploy mule apps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved , Problem is not with the command.But with the jenkins...
Just by following below 2 steps , issue is resolved.

sudo visudo
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 0):

It maybe your mistype or not cut&paste but I believe you have wrong command **su-**
It looks like it messes with you command and sudo does not see command at all.

If you need **su** then it should be **su -** but I do not believe you need one at all.

You just copy file already as root (because of sudo) you don't need to be root again.

Some advice. Listen for system messages - don't use root access. Adjust your privileges/groups/permissions so your process can write to this directory without root access.
Second, since it is partially cloud and network is potentially slow - do not copy directly to apps folder. Copy to temporary location on the same file system where apps is and then move file to aps.

Mule runtime checks apps folder every 5 seconds for new apps. If file is not comleteley copied it could damage deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by incorrect setting of permissions, and was actually asked before at [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

Having said that, using root access for building and deployment is actually a bad security practice and should be avoided. You could use `sudo -u USER` for a specific user. In your command line I can see the script is deploying to the home directory of user `ec2-user`, so you should be using that one to limit access.

Comment: Hi Aled,Alex... I tried with sudo, sudo su  - , sudo su ec2-user, sudo -u ec2-user.... but still i am facing the issue.   but i execute the same commands form terminal , i am able to move the file.                                                                                                                              
     sudo cp '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven_add/addition/target/addition-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar' /home/ec2-user/Downloads/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.3.0/apps

Comment: Are you executing the command from the terminal with exactly the same user than Jenkins?

Comment: yes... as a ec2-user i am able to copy data from source to target by using the below command.

Comment: sudo cp '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven_add/addition/target/addition-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar' /home/ec2-user/Downloads/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.3.0/apps

Comment: If Jenkins is using user ec2-user, what does it need the sudo for?

Answer (score 0):

The image is from the linux terminal. But, if i execute the same in the jenkins shell , it is the throwing the error