# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified when trying to run Shell script from JENKINS AWS instance

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a basic docker command using shell script from my Jenkins in AWS Ubuntu instance.
When I am trying to run like: 
**sudo docker build mavendocker:1.0.0 .**
I am getting below error:
[image]

I tried to change the visudo following:
[How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)
but it screwed my visudo file of AWS Ubuntu instance.

Is there any other way, I can execute my Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

Above problem is resolved following: 
https://sgoyal.net/2016/11/18/run-a-shell-from-jenkins-using-sudo-ubuntu/