# Azure Pipelines is it possible to run bash command with sudo?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sudo, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So I tried bash task and powershell task and everytime I need to run as elevated sudo user it will fail stating:

```
"sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"
```

lets say I want to run `sudo apt-get update` using powershell task.
Is there an option of doing these things? So far we were only using windows deployment group but we need to use ubuntu this time and I cannot find a solution to that.

Comment: Did you try for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107529/2347999)? (I assumed that you use self hosted agents)

Comment: actually Krzysztof answer did fixed the issue. I was messing with wrong user.
So yes, modifying sudo visudo and adding your user NOPASSWD:ALL did worked for me. Cannot mark it as answer as it sits as comment